# python os.mkdir - [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, dataset, google-colaboratory

I am using colab and I am trying to make new directory and copying files to specific location.
When I am using this code:

```
original_dataset_dir = 'D:/5-2_python_exercise/kaggle_original_data'

# The directory where we will store our smaller dataset
base_dir = "D:/5-2_python_exercise/cats_and_dogs_small"
os.mkdir(base_dir)

# Directory with our training cat pictures
train_cats_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(train_cats_dir)

# Copy first 1000 cat images to train_cats_dir
fnames = ['cat.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dataset_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(train_cats_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

I receiving this error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-b5aa61d7131f> in <cell line: 8>()
      6 # store our smaller dataset
      7 base_dir = "D:/5-2_python_exercise/cats_and_dogs_small"
----> 8 os.mkdir(base_dir)
      9 
     10 # Directories for our training,

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/5-2_python_exercise/cats_and_dogs_small'
```

But, if I replace the slash to double back slash (/ -> \\ )
I receiving this error (I check my directory and its empty)

```
FileExistsError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-e68893f49620> in <cell line: 8>()
      6 # store our smaller dataset
      7 base_dir = "D:\\5-2_python_exercise\\cats_and_dogs_small"
----> 8 os.mkdir(base_dir)
      9 
     10 # Directories for our training,

FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'D:\\5-2_python_exercise\\cats_and_dogs_small'
```

If I changing the name of the base_dir:

`base_dir = "D:\\5-2_python_exercise\\cats_and_dogs_small3"`,
I receiving an error because the name of the file is added with / and not \:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-e68893f49620> in <cell line: 45>()
     46     src = os.path.join(original_dataset_dir, fname)
     47     dst = os.path.join(train_cats_dir, fname)
---> 48     shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
     49 
     50 # Copy next 500 cat images to validation_cats_dir

/usr/lib/python3.9/shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    262         os.symlink(os.readlink(src), dst)
    263     else:
--> 264         with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
    265             try:
    266                 with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\5-2_python_exercise\\kaggle_original_data/cat.0.jpg'
```

as I said, I tried to change the locations of the dataset and the destination, it slightly helps, but not solving the problem.
I expecting to make the image copying work.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) Instead, add the appropriate code/errors/data as text in your question.